# How to offer the "-feature" option to Scala console?

Tags: scala

When I enter the code `for(i<-1 to 10 reverse) print(i + " ")` in Scala console, it shows me a warning :

`warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details`

I don't know how to offer the `-feature` option to Scala console. 
I tried to launch console by `scala --feature`, but it didn't work.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: you misspelled. nither `--fearture` nor `--feature`, it's `-feature`

Comment: `-feature` works, thx. @ymonad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2.11 also lets you turn it on:

```
scala> :se +feature
```

or off

```
scala> :se -feature
```

or explicitly

```
scala> :se -feature:true
```

That last bit was a recent update to settings; probably the redundant forms are confusing and will go away, right?

Comment: Is `se` short for "software environment"?

Comment: `:settings` actually. It takes the unambiguous prefix.

Answer (score 4):

Just enter `:warnings` into the console to see them.

Comment: I think the semantics is "last warning," not all for the session.